# Marking GridView item as selected

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm trying to create an Icon selector. The icon selector activity opens once I click on an icon in Main activity:

```
Intent intent_open_icon_picker = new Intent(Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.this, Activity_Icon_Picker.class);
intent_open_icon_picker.putExtra("SELECTED_ICON", current_icon_position);
startActivityForResult(intent_open_icon_picker, Constants.Request_Codes.REQUEST_CODE_SET_TRIP_ICON);
```

`current_icon_position` by default is 0, setting the first icon in the array to the ImageView.

Then in row_grid.xml I have this code, for each row in GridView (notice the background):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false" >
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the `@drawable/grid_color_selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_BLUE" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_BLUE" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_WHITE"/>
</selector>
```

When the icon picker activity opens - I want automatically highlight (or mark as selected) the current icon (the one that I corresponds to `current_icon_position` that I pass in the Intent). So I tried a few things, but none seems to work. I tried to do this:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{
    curr_icon_position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SELECTED_ICON");
}

grid_view = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_icons);
adapter = new GridView_Adapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, get_icons(), curr_icon_position);
grid_view.setAdapter(adapter);
**grid_view.setSelection(curr_icon_position);**
```

Then I tried to make a boolean flag in my Trip_Icon object and set it like that:

```
private ArrayList get_icons() {
    final ArrayList arr_trip_icons = new ArrayList();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.trip_icons_blac);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        Trip_Icon current_icon = new Trip_Icon(bitmap);
        **if(i==curr_icon_position)
        {
            current_icon.setSelected(true);
        }**
        arr_trip_icons.add(current_icon);
    }
    imgs.recycle();

    return arr_trip_icons;

}
```

and in my adapter do something like that:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layout_resource_id, parent, false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Trip_Icon icon = (Trip_Icon) data.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(icon.getImage());
    **if(icon.isSelected())
    {
        row.setSelected(true);
    }**

    return row;
}
```

But as I said, I never see the icon highlighted.

Just to be clearer, this is what I want to do - if the `current_icon_position` is 0, then I want the first item in the GridView to be highlighted, like in the picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I make a current icon be highlighted?

Comment: Do you want to highlight the view when selected i get?

Comment: @SuppressWarnings It does highlight an item when I click on it, but I want the current item to be highlighted automatically, marking that item as selected, so the user would now what is the currently selected item.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings I update my question with an image of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Igal do u get the Answer ?

Comment: @Igal i also Looking For Something Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414396/how-to-hold-the-selected-image-in-gridview-and-pass-to-next-activity-after-i-cli

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, after many, many tries and errors, looks like somehow I managed to solve this problem. Maybe this solution will be useful to somebody else:

First of all I added this line to my GridView:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Then I added this line to my `@drawable/grid_color_selector`:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/color_BLUE" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

And finally in my icon picker activity I added this line, after the adapter was set to Grid_view:

```
grid_view.setItemChecked(curr_icon_position, true);
```

And `curr_icon_position`, as I stated in the question, is being passed as Intent extra.